Show Desktop keyboard shortcut being reset after macos update
The default keyboard shortcut for Show Desktop is F11 on MacOS. However, I changed it to F8 because it conflicts with one of VSCode shortcuts. (Step Into for debugging)
Today, I've noticed that it's being reset when I update the MacOS version, which I always do whenever available. Is there a way to prevent it from being reset so I don't have to customize it every time I update my macOS?
